# I can't install python extension on Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Unable to start the Python language server. Make sure to install pylsp 0.19 or newer by running: python -m pip install ‘python-lsp-server[all]’ python -m pip install git+https://github.com/tomv564/pyls-mypy.git

So I’m using Kubuntu 21.04 and I’m messing with this error over an hour. What do I do? I got pylsp and python both installed. I tried reinstalling from deb instead of snap package, didn’t fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (but on Windows).

I could solve it by passing the absolute path of the Python Executable, that I used to install pylsp, into the settings of the "ide-python" package (in Atom: File->Settings->Packages->ide-python), as explained here: https://habr.com/en/post/562690/ (towards the end of the post).